# Como proteger uma API stateless, construída sobre a framework Adonis, contra ataques CSRF e XSS?

Tags: node.js, adonisjs

Considere uma API REST `stateless` com todos os endpoints protegidos com autenticação, excepto o endpoint para autenticação.

O endpoint de autenticação retorna um `JWT` que posteriormente é enviado em todas as requisições através do header `Authorization`.

O `JWT` é armazenado pelo frontend em um cookie, portanto não é um cookie `HTTPOnly`, assim sendo a API é protegida contra ataques `CSRF`, porém fica vulnerável a ataques `XSS`.

**Como proteger uma API stateless, construída sobre a framework Adonis, contra ataques CSRF e XSS?**

Comment: Não entendo porque foi marcada como ampla demais. A pergunta tem um contexto bem definido, previnir ataques XSS e CSRF em API stateless utilizando a framework Adonis.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive essa mesma pergunta quando criei duas aplicacoes usando EXPRESS, uma na arquitetura MVC e outra em REST API. Basicamente, se voce escolhe um caminho (MVC ou REST), ele te previne de CSRF, mas te deixa vulneravel a XSS, e vice-versa.

No seu caso, se voce usa arquitetura `stateful` no Adonis, a biblioteca [`shield`](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/csrf). Se voce esta em uma arquitetura `stateless`, sendo voce o responsavel pelo front-end tambem, para se proteger de ataques XSS, o script da aplicacao (do lado do cliente ou do servidor) deve sempre escapar (limpar por assim dizer), a entrada do usuário antes de gravá-la em HTML ou no banco de dados(por exemplo transformar `<` em `&lt;`, `>` em `&gt;`, e por ai vai.). Se voce usa frameworks como o Angular, ele promove este recurso de "limpar" os dados do usuario por padrao, prevenindo o ataque XSS.

Se você usa o React.js, voce nunca manipula o DOM diretamente, portanto, seu aplicativo também está protegido contra ataques XSS. o React nos impede de injetar código HTML diretamente em nossos componentes. Ele renderiza o HTML como uma string. Isso é ótimo, mas às vezes precisamos inserir código HTML em nossos componentes. Neste momento, depende da atenção, muita atenção e testes do desenvolvedor durante a codificacao para construir um código invulnerável a XSS.
[Este link](https://www.dev.education/blog/2019/01/22/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-react) fala sobre como prevenir ataque XSS em ReactJS.
Agora, se o front-end nao esta na sua responsabilidade, creio que voce devera ter uma longa conversa com a equipe responsavel pelo front.

Esta materia ["Your API-Centric Web App Is Probably Not Safe Against XSS and CSRF"](https://www.redotheweb.com/2015/11/09/api-security.html) fala sobre como se proteger de CSRF e XSS e os pos e contras de se usar `Token`, `Web Storage` e`Authorization Header` e `Session cookie`.
Eu espero ter ajudado, pois foi o que eu descobrir pesquisando e estou muito disposto a saber mais do assunto caso alguem queira comentar minha resposta.